# tf2onnx.convert has no attribute from_saved_model

Tags: machine-learning, object-detection, onnx, efficientnet, tf2onnx

I am trying to convert my custom objectdetection model .pb to .onnx model
here is the code snippet

```
import tf2onnx

# Replace with your paths
saved_model_path = '/path/to/saved_model'
onnx_export_path = '/path/to/model.onnx'

# Convert SavedModel to ONNX
tf2onnx.convert.from_saved_model(saved_model_path, output_path=onnx_export_path)
```

System information

OS Platform and Distribution: WINDOW
TensorFlow Version:2.15.1
Python version: 3.9.12
ONNX version (if applicable, e.g. 1.1.*):1.15.1
ONNXRuntime version (if applicable, e.g. 1.11*):1.16.2
To Reproduce
I read the library tf2onnx.convert file there is no module/function with named as from_saved_model as well as from_tensorflow

Additional context
my existed model is trained with SSD EfficientNet-D2 with BiFPN

I was trying to convert my custom objectdetection EfficientNet-D2 with BiFPN .pb model to .onnx model